# Does one say birkat ha-ilanot on Shabbat?

Tags: blessing, trees

When seeing two trees in bloom during the month of Nissan, one says a once-a-year bracha known as birkat ha-ilanot. This year, Rosh Chodesh is on Shabbat. I understand that some say, according to kabbala, that the bracha is best not said on Shabbat.

**What is the normative halacha regarding saying it on Shabbat?** Is the idea of not passing over a mitzva relevant here?

Comment: What is "*normative* halacha"?

Comment: @Lee sometimes halacha says one thing and those following kabbalistic practices do something else

Comment: Because their *Halakhah* is ruled in accordance with the Qabbalah. Nevertheless, for those who don't rule strictly in accordance with the Qabbalah, the general principle is as [the RaDBa"Z](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70144/2091).

Comment: Perhaps it would be more accurate to replace "normative" with "according to the Gemara and the poseqim".

Comment: Just say it today! It doesn't have to be in the month of nisan

Comment: @DoubleAA but we are not in Nissan - I thought that was important

Comment: @mbloch for someone concerned about ein maavirin, you sure are pushing things off on small concerns. We're in the springtime aka yemei nisan

Comment: From Halachipedia since this is a good question: The Gemara Brachot 43b writes that one who sees the budding of trees in Nissan should make the Birchat Ilanot. Many Rishonim (including the Ritva Rosh Hashana 11a, Sefer Eshkol pg 68) comment that this Bracha is commonly made in Nissan but does not necessarily have to be made then. This is also the opinion of the Mishna Brurah 226:1 which states that the Bracha may be made in months other than Nissan.

Comment: Rav Ovadyah Yosef in Sh"t Yechave Daat 1:1 and Chazon Ovadyah (pg 25) argue that it should be made starting in Nissan (and not Adar to be strict and take into account the opinions of the Halachot Ketanot 2:28 and Chida in Birkei Yosef 226:2) and if one has not yet seen a tree in bloom, one should still say it in Iyar. Sedei Chemed Berachot 2:1 and Kaf Hachayim 126:1 both rule that one should not say the Bracha before or after nissan. Nitei Gavriel (Pesach 6:2) writes that it should be said in Nissan.

Comment: What do you mean by normative halacha? Are you asking if having this kabbalistic practice is common? Halacha doesn't change based on kabbalah

Comment: @DoubleAA yes I am asking what is the common practice re birkat hailanot on Shabbat

Comment: @mbloch I've seen it made on Shabbat, in Adar, and in Sivan. Do you want us to take a survey?

Comment: @mbloch Well I think you should say it today (if you see the trees) and not rule off two websites. Maybe check with your rabbi instead of relying on random quotes on two websites. How do you conclude that anyway? It's all rishonim and the mishna berura, arukh hashulchan, rmoshe feinstein, tzitz eliezer, over a couple of sefardi achronim. Are you a sefardi kabbalist? "I don't think a survey is needed - I think Lee's answer below is very clear" You can figure out what common practice is from that answer? That's literally unbelievable.

Comment: Incidentally, a bigger issue than Ein Maavirin is whether or not you have to say the blessing the first time you see the blossoms. (this makes any unnecessary delay into a Safek Berakha Levatala)

Comment: @DoubleAA I will check tomorrow with a rav b'n' - in Israel we have had flowers on orange trees for 2 months - not sure if people said the bracha then - I always heard of it as a "Nissan thing"

Comment: @mbloch "I always heard of it as a 'Nissan thing'" That's why you were predisposed to accept those opinions instead of realizing that it's a misconception and "nisan" is Orcha DeMilta Nakat. Sure perhaps most people have this idea that it's nisan only, but the dominant traditional halachic opinion is not like that. If a Rav tells you to wait till Nisan, ask him what happens if it's already Iyar.

Comment: @DoubleAA so I checked with a Rav and (separately) a *talmid chacham*. Both said that, in Israel, one waits for Nissan to say *birkat hailanot* as per the gemara. If there is a doubt that there will be no more flowers in Nissan (e.g., in a shana meuberet like this one), it is fine to say the bracha earlier. And they saw no issue in saying the bracha on shabbat, which we did therefore today. Me thinks the fact we have flowers on trees in January might have something to do with it as it is clearly not springtime then

Comment: @mbloch "As per the [most literal read of the] gemara" is what you meant to say. Those who don't accept that read aren't arguing on the Gemara.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qiẓur Shulḥan 'Arukh - Yalqut Yosef (Oraḥ Ḥayim 226:13) [states](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_19.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95B-B%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99B%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AAB%D7%94%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%92) (my translation):

> מותר לברך ברכת האילנות בשבת ויום טוב, ואין לחוש ולגזור פן ישכח ויתלוש מפרחי האילנות בשבת. אלא שלכתחילה מהיות טוב יש לברך ברכת האילנות בימות החול, כשאין חשש שיפסיד הברכה, אבל בסוף חודש ניסן כשיש חשש שלא יראה יותר אילנות של מאכל עם פרחים, אין להימנע מלברך ברכה זו בשבת. [ילקוט יוסף, ח''ג דיני ברהמ''ז וברכות עמוד תרכ. ודלא כהאור לציון שחשש משום בורר הניצוצות, שכבר כתב הרדב''ז דגמרא וקבלה הלכה כהגמרא].
>
> It is permitted to recite Birkat HaIlanot on Shabbat and Yom Tov, and we do not suspect that one will forget [that it is Shabbat or Yom Tov] and will pluck flowers from the trees. Nevertheless, *ex ante facto* it is best to recite Birkat HaIlanot on a weekday if there is no concern that one will forget to recite the blessing altogether.
>
> But, at the end of the month of Nissan when there is a concern that one will not see any more flowering fruit trees, one should not avoid reciting the blessing on Shabbat [or Yom Tov]. [... And not like the Or LeẒiyon who was concerned about correcting reincarnated souls [on Shabbat and Yom Tov] for, as the RaDBa"Z wrote, "when the Gemara and Qabbalah are at odds, the Halakhah is like the Gemara"].